# Change author in multiple filtered commits

Tags: git, svn, visual-sourcesafe

I'm just converting old repositories (SVN & VSS) to Git and in these is a lot of erroneous information I want to correct. I have erroneous authors / committers standing in some time blocks because same users have worked with 2 logins and here the login of a colleague was used.

I used git filter with the --after option to find the corresponding commit IDs and now have a text file in which the commit IDs have to be stored line by line, where only the author has to be replaced.

I have now tried with

```
git commit --amend --author="<my new author>" --no-edit <commit hash>
```

to replace the respective commits now, but I always get a message here

```
did not match any file(s) known to git
```

As I understood it, I first have to check out the commit, then change it, and then rebase it. Only then would all filtered commit IDs change.

I need a solution where I go through every line of the text file and then set the author for each of the IDs and rebase at the end:

```
for i in $(cat /tmp/commitids.txt); do 
    <I dont know the correct git command to replace the author of the commit in $1> 
done; 
<I don't know the correct rebase command for all the changes>
```

Comment: You are trying to amend a revision without actually checking it out. That can't be done _just like that_. I think you would be better served by doing the svn-fetch again providing an _authors_ file.... or using filter-branch in order to fix the author revisions.

Answer (score 1):

You want filter-branch, it handles the id rewrites for you, you just supply the content and metadata changes.  In your case, assuming your commitids file is tab-separated hash code, author name, author email, it's going to be something very close to (keyboard-to-textbox warning)

```
git filter-branch --setup '
        declare -A authors; while read id auth; do authors[$id]=$auth; done <commitids
    ' --env-filter '
        [[ -v authors[$GIT_COMMIT] ]] && {
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=${authors[$GIT_COMMIT]}     
                GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=${authors[$GIT_COMMIT]}
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=${GIT_AUTHOR_NAME%$'\t'*}
                GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=${GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL#*$'\t'}
        }
    '
```

Comment: With git filter-branch I cannot filter for a time range, but this is necessary. With this code I just replace all authors items with my configured user settings, but in my case this is wrong. My current filter is is

    git log --after={2018-05-01} --author="<my searched author>"

and I need to replace it with

    git commit --amend --author="<another author, but not $GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL>" --no-edit

Comment: Well, once I fixed a typo in the substitution, it'll only replace the author on commits listed in `commitids`.

Comment: @jthill That's the most complicated `filter-branch` I've ever seen! It appears to do the thing, but in order to understand your answer, one must be an expert with both bash and git.

Comment: @jpaugh I guess I've lost all perspective then, I see it reading a file into an array then tab-splitting fields out of the string-value entries, where's the complication? (edit: spelling)

Comment: @jthill Probably the biggest challenge is to infer the format of the `commitids` file. Before being able to do that, one must infer the meaning of `--setup` and `read`. Oh, and how to filter and generate the commit IDs. If I think of it later, I will come back and add a `git log` or `rev-parse` or whats-it for that.

Comment: @jpaugh waiting for the starhopper test, I read  "assuming your commitids file is tab-separated hash code, author name, author email" and can't see what's left to infer about the format there.

Comment: @jthill I don't think English is nearly as precise as you give it credit to be. I'm guessing that adding an example file, plus showing how to generate the list of commits filtered by date would be enough for the OP to give an upvote + accept. Anyway, just my two cents. I'm waiting for a [rocket ship bound for Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_(rocket_and_spacecraft)#Starhopper).